# Access JSON nested key value with multiple endpoints Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nested

I have three different endpoints; Posts, Users and Comments. I want to GET all the data through URLSession and decode the nested values. I am trying to decode userId in the posts array to get the Users information and id in posts array to get the PostId in comments and then display in table view.

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts,

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users,

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments.

I have been using struct to get the JSON data but i don't know how to inherit a keyedcontainer. Any ideas??

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
{
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  }
```

My Code looks like this;

```
import Foundation
var allUsers = [Users]()
var allPosts = [Posts]()
class Posts: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}
class Users: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let username: String
}
let postURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
let userURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
//let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: postURL!)
func parseJSON(){
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postURL!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { print("error with data"); return }
        do {
            allPosts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Posts].self, from: data);
            //interupt the main thread and update the table with the retrieved data

            dump(allPosts)
        } catch let err {
            print("Error: ", err)
        }
    }.resume() // start the network call
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: userURL!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { print("error with data"); return }
        do {
            allUsers = try JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data);
            //interupt the main thread and update the table with the retrieved data
            dump(allUsers)
        } catch let err {
            print("Error: ", err)
        }
        }.resume() // start the network call
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you mean with *how to inherit a keyedcontainer.*?

Comment: Basically, i want to get the title from the posts url and display this into a table view. Then i want to use a segue to display the users information. I am having trouble doing this part because there are multiple urls and i don't know how to decode a nested object within a different url.